# Why does a browser action's default icon reapper after a custom icon was applied?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I have a strange problem with a browser action icon in Chrome. There is a default icon for browser action defined in manifest. The icon is displayed correctly. Then in a background page, under some conditions, I call:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"green_32.png", tabId:request.tabId});
```

This icon blinks for a moment, and then changes back to the default icon. The active tab and its id passed to `setIcon` remain the same during all the process.

Can someone suggest an idea why this can happen?

Comment: I made a small extension to test that. It changes the browser action icon periodically and everything seems to work just fine: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8989748/catExtension.zip . So your problem is not in the `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`, you need to give some more details. Try to reproduce your bug on my minimal example.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel, your extension works, thanks. Mine works as well - in regard to setting icon, but then it strangely changes back - that was the question, and you are right that there was something more important, which I couldn't figure out until last minute ;-). Just now I got it and going to post an answer.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Thanks for posting such a exhaustive answer, this information may come in handy one day. I agree that this should be documented. Consider reporting this on http://crbug.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the icon was reset to default state every time is because I called `setIcon` **before** the tab finishes loading and obtains *"complete"* state.

I guess there should be some information about this in documentation on [tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) or on [browser actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html), but I didn't find it: the default icon is actually applied - by-design - to a specific page after it finishes loading. I moved the call `setIcon` into `tabs.onUpdated` handler, and now custom icon persists.

This contradicts to my former understanding that the browser action icon is set on a per tab basis, regarless to a page loaded into the tab and its state.

@KonradDzwinel kindly provided a simple extension to test the case (look at the comments). I changed its *background.js* script to demonstrate this behaviour:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab)
{
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'gfx/icon2.png', tabId: tab.id});
});
```

To reproduce this behaviour, on any tab press the browser action icon to get it changed. Then refresh the page. As a result the browser action icon reset back to default.

If this behaviour is explained in some documentation, please, write this in comments, and I'll update the answer. From what I have read so far, I was convinced that default icon is set for new tab at its creation time, and then any changes to it are solely under extension's control.

Comment: thank you. same problem. was. documetation says: `Automatically resets when the tab is closed.`. :(